# getIntent() inside a fragment

Tags: java, android

When I try to call an intent in a fragment, I get "Cannot resolve method getIntent()".

Here is my code

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_browse_product,null);

    if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Exit me", false)){
        finish();
        return; // add this to prevent from doing unnecessary stuffs
    }

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarBrowse);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    spnCategory = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory);

    spnCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You use

`getActivity().getIntent()`

instead of

```
getIntent()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle=getArgument();
```

if you have passed bundle in intent.